# FFMpeg Trailing options were found on the commandline

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Running FFMPEG CLI and can't get rid of this warning: `Trailing options were found on the commandline.`

Command:

```
 ffmpeg \
    -hide_banner \
    -y \
    -loglevel warning \
    -i "$input" \
    "$destination" \
    -map 0 \
    -c copy \
    -c:v "$ENCODER" \
    -preset "$PRESET" \
    -crf "$CRF" \
    -tune "$TUNE" \
    -threads "$THREADS"
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Solutions to some ffmpeg errors and messages](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Errors):

> Trailing options were found on the commandline

This message is often overlooked by users and is caused by improper option placement. Placement of options matters, and trailing options are often ignored. Placement is as follows:

```
ffmpeg [global options] [input options] -i input [output options] output
```

The documentation will often specify if an option is global, input, and/or output.

Place your options in the correct location. Options before -i will be applied to the input, and options before the output name will be applied to the output. Options after the last output may be ignored.

Comment: In this case, move `"$destination"` to be the last argument.